# RangeError in libxmljs in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, libxml-js

I'm trying to replace lengthy XML tags with int values. Example '' as '<1>' so every tag with the name 'child' in the whole XML file will be replaces as '1'. I'm using libxmljs in NodeJS for this. So far my code is ;

```
    var libxml = require('libxmljs');
var xml =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
           '<root>' +
               '<child foo="bar">' +
                   '<grandchild baz="fizbuzz">grandchild content</grandchild>' +
               '</child>' +
               '<child foo="bar1">' +
                   '<grandchild baz="fizbuzz">grandchild content 1</grandchild>' +
               '</child>' +
               '<sibling>with content!</sibling>' +
           '</root>';


var xmlDoc = libxml.parseXml(xml);
var allxml = xmlDoc.root();  //store all nodes as allxml
var allNodes = xmlDoc.childNodes(); //all child nodes to array
rec(allxml);

function rec(anElement){
for (var j=0; j<allNodes.length;j++ )
    {
        var firstnode = allNodes[j].name(); //get tagname of the element

        var findelem = xmlDoc.find(firstnode); //find similar elements with the tagname to array
        var currChild = xmlDoc.child(j); //get current child element
        var currnode = xmlDoc.childNodes(); // child nodes of current element to array
        if (hasChild(currChild)) { // check whether this has child elements
                rec(currChild.childNodes()); //if yes recall this function
            }
        else{ replaceCurrentTag(findelem, j);} // if no child nodes replace the name
    }
}

function replaceCurrentTag(currelem, j){

for (var i=0;i<currelem.length;i++){
        currelem[i].name(j.toString());
    }
}

function hasChild(xmlElement){
var e = xmlElement.childNodes();
if (e.length > 0){ return true; }
else return false;
}

console.log(xmlDoc.toString());
```

But I'm getting this error when I run it in terminal.

```
/home/compaq/node_modules/libxmljs/lib/document.js:0
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var bindings = r
^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

What is that I'm doing wrong in here.

Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rec` function iterates over `allNodes`, rather than the some subset of the nodes (probably the children of `anElement`). Combined with recursing into `rec` again before calling `replaceCurrentTag` (which never gets called), your function continues to call `rec` until you fill the call stack.